# Ebean ORM - Excluding rows which is null and with certain values

Tags: java, ebean

How do I filter rows in Ebean based on 2 conditions.

1. If the column is NULL
2. If the column is NOT NULL, check if the value meet certain condition

Here is my code. It does not return rows where the column is NULL.

```
    if(value_to_check!=null) {
      where = where.isNull("field");
      where = where.eq("field", value_to_check);
    }
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

**Update**

I have resolved the problem. The moment of duhh. :)

```
if(value_to_check!=null) {
  where = where.or(
                Expr.and(
                     Expr.isNotNull("field"),
                     Expr.ne("field", value_to_check)
                       ), 
                       Expr.isNull("field") );
}
```